# Perl: Is it possible to undo a SIG{INT} catch?

Tags: perl, signals

I'm trying to add a catch signal in my Perl program. When a ctrl+C occurs, I'd like a confirmation message, and a user input ( Y or N ). The Y input works fine.

If the user enters N, then essentially I want to "cancel" the ctrl+C command and return to the script.

The code:

```
$SIG{INT} = \&catchSignal;
$SIG{TERM} = \&catchSignal;

sub catchSignal
{
   my $ans;
   print " Are you sure you want to quit? Y or N:\n";
   $ans = <STDIN>;

   chomp $ans;

   if( $ans eq "Y" )
   {
      exit;
   }
   else
   {
      # Cancel the ctrl+C command
   }

}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Just do nothing in case of `'N'`, so what you have should already do what you want in general. But yet you haven't checked if the input is only `'Y'` or `'N'`, so essentially any input except `'Y'` discards the signal. And you have to handle the case when there's another `INT` while being in the dialog.

Comment: So a ctrl+C is given, and then catchSignal runs. Is that all there is, regarding ctrl+C? Like you said, if anything other than `'Y'` is given, essentially the subroutine ends. Is that correct? Also, what do you mean by `INT`? Another interrupt during this message?

Comment: I will add the `'Y'` and `'N'` handling; this is just the basics so far.

Comment: Yes, by "another `INT`" I meant another `INT` signal is received whilst the process is in the signal handler.

Comment: Just having a non-default `$SIG{INT}` handler already suppresses the default behavior (and a `$SIG{INT}` handler that exits is subtly different from the default handler, though I can't remember the details atm)

Comment: @stickybit The signal handler itself doesn't get interrupted and another such signal (that comes while the handler runs) is delayed and handled once the handler returns (just one, more extra signals are lost in my sketchy test); so they're safe, their program can't get killed that way.  (If they wanted to ensure to honor that second or third successive interrupt that'd be something else...).

Comment: @zdim: Hmm, that might be OS or interpreter specific? At least for me, when I tested it on Window with Active Perl 5.26.1 I got the "Are you sure ..." message again when hitting Ctrl+C when the message was already on the screen and I haven't responded yet. But indeed I then only needed to respond once.

Comment: @stickybit Hah, OK. I tried it out a little on  v5.16 (CentOS7) -- I'll try different versions. That's also stated somewhere in the docs I thought, I'll look for it again and update here

Comment: ( And if there are still questions please let us know )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a handler installed the default action of that signal is suppressed and your handler runs instead<sup>†</sup> once that signal comes in. See [Signals in perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) for starters.

So what you show already "cancels" the signal and your program will continue after the handler returns, unless the user confirms the exit of course. Where and how the program continues isn't set in stone, but generally it is from after where it was interrupted.

If a blocking system call gets interrupted by the signal then that call fails with `EINTR` (`errno(3)`).<sup>‡</sup> These error codes are mostly reflected in [`%!` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables), so when one such call returns an error we can check whether `$!{EINTR}` is set, and if it is then it may well make sense to restart that call. Thanks to `ikegami` for a comment.

Precisely what calls have this isn't set firmly, but one can infer it from `signal(7)` (see <sup>‡</sup> footnote).

If they do choose to exit that's a better way to go than being blown out of the water by a signal, since a signal with disposition to stop the program just terminates it.  While when a program calls `exit` that's controlled and one can clean up, exit with a  chosen code; also, buffers are flushed, `END` blocks run.

---

<sup>†</sup> Except for signals that can't be trapped, `STOP` (sigstop) and `KILL` (sigkill) in the first place.

<sup>‡</sup> In C we can set `SA_RESTART` in `sigaction(2)`  to have such calls restarted (see `Interruption of system calls...` in `signal(7)` for example), but not with the native `%SIG` in Perl. There is support in `POSIX::sigaction` but its use is rather involved and practically undocumented.